# Display Files in the folder using PHP

Tags: php

I have a issue in displaying files in the folder using PHP, The code that used to display is

```
<?php

$dir="public_html/Uploads"; // Directory where files are stored

if ($dir_list = opendir($dir))
{
while(($filename = readdir($dir_list)) != false)
{
?>
<p><a href="<?php echo $filename; ?>"><?php echo $filename;
?></a></p>
<?php
}
closedir($dir_list);
}

?>
```

this code is work fine in the local server where it is a wamp server and it list all the files in the folder.

But my problem is where it gives issue when i upload it to the hostgator server, it give me a 500 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `public_html/` from this line of code `$dir="public_html/Uploads";` and let me know if it works or not.

Comment: Hello thank you for the response. i remove the public_html/ but still it didnt work

Comment: check error logs so that you can have a little clearer picture about the error and what about the permission settings, have you checked it?

Comment: what the permition i have to give to the folder now i have given 757 for the folder

Comment: check the folder you are putting your files on server..is it under public_html folder and what error logs are saying? .. the code is working fine for me as i placed this under public_html folder and $dir="Uploads"; as the directory to enquire

Comment: now after changing the file permeation and the change the file path den i get this error. "No input file specified." but the folder has 2 document files

Comment: Check and supply appropriate file permissions inside the folder for those doc files and let me now if this is doing the trick

Comment: Still i have the same issue and i gave the full permission for the folders

Comment: ok..last try i included your code in abc.php file and put this file in public_html folder and investigated about the files present in my Upload folder that i mentioned in $dir="Uploads"; just check if u are placing the file in the same folder..you need to be up one level to the investigating folder

Comment: I have upload this file in the Uploads folder. is it a problem

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you have insufficient permissions.
Try using chmod:

```
chmod("public_html/Uploads", 0644);
```

Comment: hello thank you for the quick reply, any way where do i have to add this tag and do i have to remove any other tag in the code

Comment: CHMOD is a UNIX command. You can either run it through a SSH shell, your FTP client (right-click on the folder and select Permissions or something similar) or by creating a new .php script, put in that line of code, and run it once.